# SyntaxError When Trying To Run The "node ." How Do I Fix It?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I Just Started Learning in this is the error i get when trying to start the bot up.
Any Ideas On How to fix this?

The SyntaxError is:

```
    SyntaxError: C:\Users\Thela\code\config.json: Unexpected end of JSON input
        at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
        at Object.Module._extensions..json (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:987:27)
        at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:812:32)
        at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
        at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:849:19)
        at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
        at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Thela\code\index.js:2:16)
        at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:956:30)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:973:10)
        at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:812:32)
```

The index.js

```js
    const Discord = require('discord.js');
    const config = require('./config.json');
    const client = new Discord.Client();

    client.once('ready', () => {
        console.log('Ready!');
    });

    client.on('message', message => {
        if (message.content === '!ping') {
            message.channel.send('Pong.');
        }
    });

    client.login(config.token);
    enter code here
```

And The config.json is

```
    {
        "prefix": "!",
        "token": "<my-token>",
    }
```

Comment: This isn't valid JSON. Remove the second comma.

Answer (score 1):

config.json should be like this:

```
{
    "prefix": "!",
    "token": "<my-token>"
}
```

which the "," on line 3 is not supposed to be here.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike in Javascript, trailing commas are not allowed in JSON. Therefore change the config to this:

```
{
    "prefix": "!",
    "token": "<my-token>"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem does not lie within your code, but rather within your JSON configuration file.

JSON format does not allow trailing commas, so in your case this would easily be fixed by simply removing it. Your new configuration file should look like this:

```
{
    "prefix": "!",
    "token": "<my-token>"
}
```

Additionally, I've noticed the presence of `enter code here` within your code, not sure if you're removed this or have it as a comment, but leaving this intact in your code is surely bound to cause some errors.